# Converting multiple PDF files to Text files in subdirectory using Ghostscript in Windows

Tags: bash, pdf, for-loop, ghostscript, extract

OS: Windows 10 Professional

I'd like to convert multiple PDF files to text files in main and sub-directories using GhostScript on Windows command line. Here's my command below:

```
gswin64c -sDEVICE=txtwrite -o test1.txt "test1.pdf"
```

This code converts "test1.pdf" to "test1.txt" using Ghostscript but I would like to perform the following:

1. Look for all pdf files in main directory and all sub-directories
2. Execute Ghostscript on all PDF files
3. Give the same file name to the output text file. (test1.pdf -> test1.txt)

I appreciate your time and consideration on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a batch or `.cmd` file like this:

```
@echo off

REM Replace these with your actual location
D:
cd "\Main Directory"

for /R %%F in (*.pdf) do call :DOPDF "%%F"
goto ENDIT

:DOPDF
for %%X in (%1) do set PDF_TXTFNM=%%~dpnX.txt
gswin64c -sDEVICE=txtwrite -o "%PDF_TXTFNM%" %1
goto :EOF

REM Clean up
:ENDIT
set PDF_TXTFNM=
```

**EDIT TO ADD:**

Side Note:  If you do not wish to change your working directory to the main directory, be aware that `for /R %%F in ("D:\Main Directory\*.pdf") ...` will only work if there actually *is* a `.pdf` file in `D:\Main Directory`.  The two main workarounds are to make it the current working directory (the solution chosen in my example) or to force a dummy `.pdf` file to exist in that directory and then choose to not process it in the subroutine using an `IF` statement.  Holler if you need an example of that latter technique.